# django migrations not creating new tables

Tags: sql, django, migration

i am using mysql for the database and each time when i created new models i have to create new table by going in the phpmyadmin because the migration is not creating any tables but the migrate happens successfully.How can i solve this ?

Comment: sometimes the migrations are not reflected in the database. For this, django south migrations can be used. https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Comment: i tried python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto  but it says unknown command

Comment: After model edition you shoul use: `manage.py makemigrations`. Thats all, this will generate proper schema migrations.

Comment: i always do that after some changes in model

Comment: can you show settings.py db code and your models.py code @SugAt

Comment: Check out, exist the module "migrations" into the app of model Damaged, and generate the migrations files after execute the command "makemigrations".

Comment: @c.grey  i have updated my code.

Comment: Please describe the complete command you are writing for `makemigratios` and `migrate`. Also check if your models doesn't include `abstract=True`. Also please tell the changes you have made in models. And are you sure your DB does not have password set?

Comment: @Rakmo no the model doesn't include abstract=True and the DB also doesn't have password. The commands used are python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate